# Hyperledger Fabric fabcar - peer chaincode & 500 Access Errors - CLI

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I exec into the docker container for the peer and try the CLI commands for peer chaincode and peer lifecycle but they fail. I understand this is a --cafile issue but I tried a few combinations and nothing worked. This is the fabcar example with 2.0, without any changes. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Here is the example -

> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # peer lifecycle
> chaincode queryinstalled Error: query failed with status: 500 - Failed
> to authorize invocation due to failed ACL check: Failed verifying that
> proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless
> check policy with policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under
> this MSP [Org2MSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP:
> [Org2MSP]]
>
> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # peer chaincode
> list --installed Error: bad response: 500 - access denied for
> [getinstalledchaincodes]: Failed verifying that proposal's creator
> satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with
> policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under this MSP
> [Org2MSP]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [Org2MSP]]

And env -

> CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false HOSTNAME=6bc772022b6b
> CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
> CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
> CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:9051 SHLVL=1
> HOME=/root CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
> CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
> CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
> CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
> CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9052
> CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=net_test
> FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
> CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
> TERM=xterm CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
> FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric
> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
> CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME= CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
> CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
> CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
> CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
> PWD=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
> CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
> CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
> CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:9051
> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer #

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` path in your peer docker container to the admin's `msp` directory. The default path to admin's `msp` directory is `/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`.

Set the path using the below command if `/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp` is the path of admin's `msp` directory.

`export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`

Comment: I solved finally using env vars and then commands outside of the docker containers, using localhost as the ports map to the containers.

Comment: Please add the environment variable in the comments so that it could help others who face this issue. If it's the same which I configured in my answer then consider it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes I can do that when I have this finalised. I have the original problem solved and now I have new issues related to committing. So my basic idea was to solve the problem entirely and then post a solution.

Comment: Sure, but post the solution for the problem in the current post. As it will maintain the brevity of the post.

Comment: The env vars are very complex for this, I can post the basics here when finalised. There is another post anyway about the commit.

Comment: Are these the flags that you added https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#interacting-with-the-network? In case of "yes", add only the flags in your answer which resulted in resolving the issue and not the whole group.

Comment: No 2.0. It is all about setting environment variables. There is no value posting a solution which solves one problem and not others.

Comment: I saw this had a -1 vote anyway, so I guess no one wants the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The answer needs to use env vars to solve the problem. The question was voted negative so I will not post the answer details as no one needs them.