# Hyperledger Fabric: "err: bad proposal response 500: access denied" when trying to join peer to channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Built a network, added orderers to the channel here referenced as: channelname
The following folders are mounted on the container

```
# docker-compose.yaml
    volumes:
      - "~/container-volumes/$docker_peer0/production:/var/hyperledger/production"
      - "~/organizations/peerOrganizations/$company/peers/$docker_peer0/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp"
      - "~/organizations/peerOrganizations/$company/peers/$docker_peer0/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls"
```

Trying to join a peer to a channel, but gives `bad proposal response 500: access denied.`

---

1. Build the channel configuration block with the following command:

```
./configtxgen -profile SampleAppChannelEtcdRaft -outputBlock genesis_block.pb -channelID channelname
```

2. Next joined the orderers to the channel using the following command with an identity enrolled with role admin

```
./osnadmin channel join --channel-id channelname  --config-block ~/Downloads/bin/genesis_block.pb -o localhost:9440 --ca-file $OSN_TLS_CA_ROOT_CERT --client-cert $ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT --client-key $ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY
```

3. Next I copy the generated genesis_block.pb to a mounted folder on the container so it is reachable for the following command which we use to join the peer to the channel:

```
docker exec -it peer0 peer channel join -b /var/hyperledger/production/genesis_block.pb -o vm01:9440 --clientauth --cafile /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/tls/tls-ca-cert.pem --certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/user/peer-admin/tls/cert.pem --keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/user/peer-admin/tls/key.pem
```

- This results in the following error

```
[channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][channelname]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [The identity is not an admin under this MSP [org1msp]: The identity does not contain OU [ADMIN], MSP: [org1msp]]])
```

The admin used for this command is peer-admin that was enrolled with the TLS-CA and the organizational CA. Also the config.yaml for OU's is present in peer-admin msp.

I also tried to set the `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to the msp dir of peer-admin (peer0/msp/user/peer-admin/msp), but this results on a hard exit of the container on startup. [fabric-chaincode-500-access-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63167720/hyperledger-fabric-fabcar-peer-chaincode-500-access-errors-cli)

I can't seem to figure out where it goes wrong, has it something to do with the `--cafile`, `--certfile` or `--keyfile` that you have to set within the peer channel join command or something else?

Edit:

This is the config file.

```
  $docker_peer1_service_name:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.3
    container_name: $docker_peer1_container_name
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric
      - CORE_PEER_ID=$docker_peer1
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=test
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7081
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7082
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=localhost:7082
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7081
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=msp
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=$company
      - CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=/var/hyperledger/production
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=127.0.0.1:7091
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=localhost:7081
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=localhost:7081
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/key.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/tls-ca-cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES=tls/tls-ca-cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/key.pem
      - CORE_PEER_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_PEER_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=peer1-couchdb:5985
      - CORE_PEER_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=$docker_peer1_couchdb_username
      - CORE_PEER_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=$docker_peer1_couchdb_pass
      - CORE_PEER_LEDGER_SNAPSHOTS=var/hyperledger/production/snapshots
      #- CORE_PEER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=127.0.0.1:9443
      #- CORE_PEER_OPERATIONS_TLS_ENABLED=true
      #- CORE_PEER_OPERATIONS_TLS_CERT_FILE=
      #- CORE_PEER_OPERATIONS_TLS_KEY_FILE=
      #- CORE_PEER_OPERATIONS_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED=true
      - CORE_PEER_METRICS_PROVIDER=disabled
      #- CORE_PEER_METRICS_STATSD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:8125
      #- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=127.0.0.1:9444
    ports:
      - "7081:7081"
      - "7082:7082"
      - "7091:7091"
    volumes:
      - "~/container-volumes/$docker_peer1/production:/var/hyperledger/production"
      - "~/organizations/peerOrganizations/$company/peers/$docker_peer1/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp"
      - "~/organizations/peerOrganizations/$company/peers/$docker_peer1/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! As a helpful tip, SO supports [markdown for formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), which should help to make future posts like these easier to read and follow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to set the MSPID to use when you are running the `peer channel join ...` command.

Try setting `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` to `org1msp`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is what I am already using. Above I put the config file.